# Non-recursive Backtrack using Queue: runs out of memory

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, out-of-memory, backtracking

I have tried to implement a [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) example program by using a [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) container, in the C++11 dialect.

However there is a coding mistake somewhere in the algorithm that causes the program to run out of memory. What is that mistake?

In the code sample below, the functions `reject()`, `accept()`, `first_child()` and `next_child()` may be assumed to work correctly, because they have been tested successfully with recursive and `std::stack` container [implementations of backtracking](https://github.com/ab396356/little_test_programs/blob/a5e77f347bb068f43708282d2183edb84e651c60/cpp_misc/backtrack.cpp).

```cpp
// helper functions
bool reject(const std::string &c);
bool accept(const std::string &c);
const std::string * first_child(const std::string &c);  // nullptr == no child
const std::string * next_child(const std::string &c);   // nullptr == no child

void backtrack_que(const std::string &start)
try
{
    std::queue<std::string> que;

    que.push(start);

    while (!que.empty())
    {
        if (reject(que.front()))
        {
            que.pop();
            continue;
        }

        if (accept(que.front()))
            std::cout << que.front() << '\n';

        const std::string *p_child(first_child(que.front()));

        que.pop();

        if (p_child != nullptr)
        {
            que.push(*p_child);

            const std::string *p_sibling(next_child(que.back()));

            while (p_sibling != nullptr)
            {
                que.push(*p_sibling);
                p_sibling = next_child(que.back());
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "unknown exception in `" << __func__ << '`' << std::endl;
    throw;
}
```

Comment: For each string you pop, you add 36 longer strings. If you start with an empty string, you'll end up with some 36^5=60+ million strings in the queue, which by rough estimate would take over 1GB of RAM. If you start with a string longer than 5 characters, then your loop never stops at all.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for spotting the `length > 5` bug in `first_child()`. As for the out-of-memory bug, I have difficulties understanding why it doesn't also happen when `std::stack` is used.

Comment: The stack version has the same problem, as far as I can tell. My guess would be, `std::stack` uses `std::vector` underneath while `std::queue` uses `std::deque`. The latter has somewhat higher overhead per element. So your 60+M strings just manage to fit into RAM with stack, but run out with queue.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik According to [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), `std::stack` also uses `std::deque` by default, and I have not changed the default to `std::vector`. So I did further testing, as detailed in my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have performed a simple counting test and found that @IgorTandetnik was accurate regarding the *Queue* variant: it reached 60+ million maximum size.

Surprisingly to me, the *Stack* variant didn't exceed 200. Upon revisiting the code I concluded that this is due to how the *Stack* variant "rushes" to last possible child while the *Queue* variant accumulates a great number of children before going further to the next generation: in more computer-sciency terms, *Stack* does [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) while *Queue* does [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Also surprising was that, apparently, the traditional *Recursive* variant seems to be the most efficient and also the fastest.

```
max recursion depth for bt-rec: 6
max container size for bt-stk:  176
max container size for bt-que:  60466176
```